# Is it possible for psychological trauma to cause a lasting coma?

Tags: science-based, biology

So, I was thinking about flavouring psychic damage and thought "If I'm *anime > western civilization*, then wouldn't it make sense for me to reflect it a bit more?"

In an anime, I watched, there was this episode where one of the main characters was attacked with a special "ray of light" that basically allowed the attacker to dig up the character's supressed memories, forcing her to live through them again in a personalized hell, essentially. Said character wasn't hurt physically, but fell into a coma and stayed like that until the last two episodes.

My idea was the excessive psychic damage **could render people unconscious for variable periods of time.**

Problem is, psychic damage can't truly change your brain, **it can't access the brainstem and make you stop breathing. It can, however, deceive your senses and alter your hormone levels to an extent.**

**Particularly vivid hallucinations tend to trigger the release of a paralyzing chemical in creatures to prevent them from injuring or killing themselves.** The admin put that defense there becuase "Screw your manchurian gold, I have sleeping pills!"

**So, I wanted to know if its possible to make an average person fall into a coma (that stays there for a while, even after the hallucinations are gone), soley by forcing them to live through something incredibly horrifying in their head?**

Comment: Gonna have to go with "dubious"... average people have to live through horrifying things all the time, and there don't seem to be a whole lot of cases of actual coma resulting from something other than physical trauma or disease. Don't really have enough to throw an answer together, though.

Comment: You should look into psychosomatic medicine, it is the study of how mind related issues (stress and such) can have a physical effect.

Answer (score 1):

For evidence-based psychic attacks:  as the question is currently formed, no. It is not possible to have the *sole mechanism* for going into a coma be the act of forcefully remembering something.

However, this is not because the memories can't cause psychological harm.  It's because there must be a physical mechanism working on the brain.

Memories exist in physical form in the brain, though the specific encoding mechanism is still a mystery.  Thoughts are a physical process in the brain, with all sorts of cells participating in chemical and ion channel reactions. -- This is why, when you repeat a word several times in a short period, it starts to sound strange: you have temporarily used up a cache of chemicals that help encode thoughts related to that word.

In order to force a memory, you must force a physical reaction inside of a living mind.  This is possible, though currently not with any precision.  [Transcranial magnetic stimulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation) (TMS) can have some very dramatic effects, for example.  In order to induce specific memories, though, you would need to target magnetic fields on a sub-cellular basis (you need to target specific dendrites in a neuron).  Popular science fiction worlds with that level of technology include Star Trek, the most advanced races of Doctor Who (I.e., Daleks, Time Lords), and anyone who can use sensors that can peek inside of another ship and "scan for life signs" (as a popular trope).

So, if you can have a science-based way to induce specific memories, you have a science-based way to induce a coma that is far simpler feature of your psychic attack weapon.

A coma can certainly be a side effect of inducing memories, though...  After all, to quote Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind:

> Joel: Is there any risk of brain damage?
>   Howard: Technically speaking, the procedure *is* brain damage.

Comment: Doubt you'd get the resolution you need from TMS alone, but as the OP's world includes all-powerful and pervasive nanomechanisms they can probably fix it... tunnel their way in through the olfactory bulb and prod the synapses directly, sort of thing.

Comment: Indeed; we can't even trap plasma magnetically with enough precision to keep a fusion reaction going, and that takes magnetic fields on the orders of a few meters wide.  Having precise enough _and dynamic enough_ manipulation of any sort of fields to produce the effects of TMS on thousands of very specific dendrite-level structures on the brain is in the realm high-sci-fi.  (not hard sci-fi.  Winchell Chung of Atomic Rockets would definitely frown on this.)

Comment: @StarfishPrime The question is then, why are they still limited to A and not B instead.

Answer (score 1):

**It's possible as a side effect**

A weapon designed to send the target into a coma seems like a pretty effective weapon, at first glance, anyway. After all, it's nonlethal, right? Except, it's not really like that. The coma type you're looking at is a known as less than 8-9 on the Glasgow Coma Scale (which goes from 3-15) and is bad. People have recovered from lasting comas, but it's generally the exception, not the rule, and any weapon that can cause this may also cause death. But in your example you do mention that it's actually a side effect of a traumatic psychic weapon, which presumably seeks less to coma-tize the target, but rather just render them incapable of fighting.

It's now that I reference your previous question, [How could an illusion effect covering all senses scare someone to death?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161175/how-could-an-illusion-effect-covering-all-senses-scare-someone-to-death), and my answer - it's possible, though unlikely, to trigger acute myocardial infarction caused by stress cardiomyopathy through nothing but images. And this can cause a coma, as a heart attack stops blood to the brain, triggering a condition known as hypoxia, which can trigger a prolonged coma. Unfortunately, hypoxia results in the kind of coma that has the patient's likelihood to recover decrease the longer they stay in the coma and as a side effect this will likely cause brain damage as well, preventing the subject from fully recovering.

So, to answer your question: If you had a weapon designed to induce acute myocardial infraction from stress cardiomyopathy, this can trigger cerebral hypoxia, which may result in a coma. Also, this is the kind of possible which is 'not technically *impossible*', not anywhere near 'likely to happen'.